# Giving full control for NETWORK SERVICE user on ASP.NET temp-folder

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

Is giving full control for the NETWORK SERVICE user on `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder a good idea?

When I deploy my app on the iis, it started complaining about this access issue.

Comment: Dunno in v4, but in v2 it's not a big difference, because NS has already read permisions, and the one who's going to create files in that folder is the IIS Asp.Net Account, not Network Service.

Comment: @carlos NS hasn't have any access on the folder I specified until I have given it.

Answer (score 3):

The appropriate way is (depending on your issue) to use `aspnet_regiis.exe -ga "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"` which "grants the specified user or group access to the IIS metabase and other directories that are used by ASP.NET".

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.80).aspx