# IIS 7.5 express error, CS0016:Could not write to output file ... ‘Access is denied.’

Tags: iis-7.5

I tried solution from this link [Giving full control for NETWORK SERVICE user on ASP.NET temp-folder](https://serverfault.com/questions/274032/giving-full-control-for-network-service-user-on-asp-net-temp-folder) also I tried set permissions manually. But nothing helps...

**Update:** My link looks like: https://localhost:44301/ When I am running my site on webmatrix it's work fine(but on another url). But VS or direct links doesn't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably running under the IUSR account.  If you go to the site and check your authentication -> anonymous authentication, you can set the user to use the app pool identity.  Then everything will run as the app pool identity.

Here's a quick video I put together that covers the main security accounts in IIS and how they should be configured: [Securing IIS](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/iis/Securing-IIS-Thwarting-the-Hacker-Week-23.aspx).

Comment: maybe I understood something wrong, but why after I add full permissions to IUSR I still have this error?

Comment: That should take care of it.  The different between the app pool user and the anonymous user depends on the application and whether it impersonates or not.  You can check out Week 20 on process monitor to help troubleshoot this better: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/iis/ProcessMon-Power-Tool-for-the-Windows-Admin-Week-20.aspx

Comment: also I set Identity to ApplicationPoolIdentity and still have error

Comment: It will run under the identity that the app pool is set at then.  Possibly the code calls out to a path that's somewhere else on disk.  Check out the two links I sent.  They cover how to track this down.